# Prove if two relations are antisymmetric then their composition is also antisymmetric

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I need someone to check if check if my reasoning is correct.

I've got to proof that:
if $\mathrel{R_1}$ and $\mathrel{R_2}$ are antisymmetric then $\mathrel{R_1} \circ \mathrel{R_2}$ is also antisymmetric.

Let:

$x\mathrel{R_3} y \Leftrightarrow x (\mathrel{R_1}\circ\mathrel{R_2})y\Leftrightarrow \exists_{z\in X} (x \mathrel{R_1} z \ \wedge z \mathrel{R_2} y) $

Let's suppose that $\mathrel{R_1}$ and $\mathrel{R_2}$ are antisymmetric and $\mathrel{R_3}$ is not antisymmetric. Then exists such $x, y \in X$ that $x\mathrel{R_3}y \ \wedge y\mathrel{R_3}x \ \wedge x \neq y $. That means $\exists_{z \in X}([x \mathrel{R_1} z \ \wedge z \mathrel{R_2} y]\Rightarrow z \neq y \neq x)$ which is not true because $\mathrel{R_1}$ and $\mathrel{R_2}$ are antisymmetric. Then $\mathrel{R_1}$ and $\mathrel{R_2}$ are antisymmetric then $\mathrel{R_1} \circ \mathrel{R_2}$ is also antisymmetric is true.

Comment: What is the definition of R_3?  You cannot custom design three relations to present a plausible situation. You must prove that *every time $R_1, R_2,$ are antisymmetric,  their composition is too.*  What do you know to be the definition of antisymmetric relation $X_1$?

Comment: With regards to where your attempt failed... "*which is not true*" is a leap in logic which is unjustified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small counterexample:

$R_1 = \{(1,2),(3,2)\}$

$R_2 = \{(2,3),(2,1)\}$

$R_1\circ R_2 = \{(1,1),(1,3),(3,1),(3,3)\}$

It is clear that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are both anti-symmetric, yet $R_1\circ R_2$ is not.